# Create unique join id-id matrix if joins parameters is not unique in order of id

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Problem is to **join 2 tables with similar data when join keys is not always unique** (Import new data from temporary to live table) 
In this case I need **resolve duplicities by order of id** (**every id should be only one time**, meaning every next *table1.id* take first non used *table2.id* and vice versa).

Note:

- User can create new records, which create more duplicates
- Query **must work in WITH section in a fraction of second** on hundred thousands records in *table1* (imported data) and thousands in table2 (live data)

**Consider these data/tables**

```
|| Imported |                                  || Live |
| Id | guid | key1 | key2 | unimportant |     | Id | origGuid | key1 | key2 |     important |
|  1 | 1001 |    1 | '01' |         'a' |     | 15 |     1001 |    1 | '01' |    'imported' |
|  2 | 1002 | null | '02' |         'b' |     | 16 |     1002 | null | '02' |    'imported' |
|  3 | 1003 | null | '02' |         'c' |     | 17 |     null | null | '02' | 'user restor' |
|  5 | 1005 |    5 | '05' |         'd' |     | 18 |     1004 |    4 | '04' |    'imported' |
                                               | 19 |     null | null | '02' |    'user new' |
```

I want to get:

- Record with id 1 from imported equals to id 15 in live (is unique)
- Record with id 2 from imported equals to id 16 in live

  - keys null & '02' is not unique, so this is first occurrence and take first id from live with same keys -> 16
- Record with id 3 from imported equals to id 17 in live

  - same keys as row with id 2 and this is second occurrence so take second id from live with same keys ->17 (This I meaning first non used)
- Record with id 5 from imported data is new

  - there is no row in live data with same keys -> null
- Record with id 18,19 in live data mark to delete

  - there is no row in imported data with same keys -> null

Here i put **query to prepare data**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE imported (id serial, guid decimal(30,0), key1 integer, key2 varchar, unimportant varchar);
INSERT INTO imported VALUES (1, 1001,    1, '01', 'a');
INSERT INTO imported VALUES (2, 1002, null, '02', 'b');
INSERT INTO imported VALUES (3, 1003, null, '02', 'c');
INSERT INTO imported VALUES (5, 1005,    5, '05', 'd');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE live (id serial, orig_guid integer, key1 integer, key2 varchar, important varchar);
INSERT INTO live VALUES (15, 1001,    1, '01',    'imported');
INSERT INTO live VALUES (16, 1002, null, '02',    'imported');
INSERT INTO live VALUES (17, null, null, '02', 'user restor');
INSERT INTO live VALUES (18, 1004,    4, '04',    'imported');
INSERT INTO live VALUES (19, null, null, '02',    'user new');
```

I used **old query** like this. But it was slow (Nested Loop Join), and result wasn't perfect (Not resolved duplicities)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT imported.id AS imported_id, live.id AS live_id
        FROM live
        INNER JOIN imported ON 
            live.orig_guid = imported.guid OR (
              (live.orig_guid IS NULL OR imported.guid IS NULL) AND 
              (live.key1 IS NULL AND imported.key1 IS NULL OR live.key1 = imported.key1) AND
              (live.key2 IS NULL AND imported.key2 IS NULL OR live.key2 = imported.key2)
            )
        ORDER BY live.id ASC, imported.id ASC
```

In **optimized query** I split SELECT to 2 with using UNION command and reduce ORs with COALESCE to speed up

```
WITH
liveT AS (SELECT id, COALESCE(orig_guid,0) AS guid, COALESCE(key1,0) AS key1, COALESCE(key2,'null') AS key2 FROM live),
importedT AS (SELECT id, COALESCE(guid,0) AS guid, COALESCE(key1,0) AS key1, COALESCE(key2,'null') AS key2 FROM imported),
join1 AS ( 
    SELECT imported.id AS imported_id, live.id AS live_id FROM imported
    INNER JOIN live ON imported.guid = live.orig_guid AND imported.guid <> 0 AND live.orig_guid <> 0
),
joins AS ( 
    SELECT imported.id AS imported_id, live.id AS live_id FROM importedT imported
        INNER JOIN liveT live ON 
            (live.guid = 0 OR imported.guid = 0) AND
            live.key1 = imported.key1 AND
            (live.key2 = imported.key2) -- I have in one key "OR imported.key2 = 'null'" because is new property and is not so strict
    -- To reduce records i use AntiJoin
    LEFT OUTER JOIN join1 ON join1.imported_id = imported.id
    WHERE join1.imported_id IS NULL

    UNION 
    SELECT imported_id, live_id FROM join1
)
SELECT DISTINCT imported_id, live_id FROM joins
ORDER BY imported_id ASC NULLS LAST, live_id ASC NULLS LAST
```

But result is not perfect, and use 3 similar query

- this is for getting connected ones (live *table2* in one module to live *table3* in another module)
- second i connect records which mark for delete from live *table3* to imported *table1*

  - for finding delete mark i use first command to get (not)connected
  - and need get new informations from imported table, is only owner is changed

    - Exists in imported *table1* and *table3*, but not transfer to *table2* because owner not match
- and last searching for used values in *table3* in context of imported *table1*

  - *table3* has association to new table (*id*, *code*, *name*)
  - imported *table1* have property *code* and *name*
  - And I need figure which records in associated table add/update/delete

**Query's results** are:

```
|| Old |                 || Optimized |          || Expected |
import_id | live_id      import_id | live_id     import_id | live_id
        1 | 15                   1 | 15                  1 | 15
        2 | 16                   2 | 16                  2 | 16
        2 | 17                   3 | 17                  3 | 17
        2 | 19                   3 | 19                  5 | null
        3 | 17                                        null | 18
        3 | 19                                        null | 19
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `distinct on ()`

Comment: I really haven't idea, how to use distinct to get result i want. Distinct only take first occurrence by order. Distinct booth values don't take any effect. Distinct first one result id 2-16, 3-16 matrix. second one result 2-16, 2-17, 2-19 matrix. And that all is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear.

You have included sample data as `INSERT` statements - this is great and helps to answer the question. You have shown the expected result - this is great as well. Usually, it helps if you explain in plain English the required logic behind this result. This part of the question is not quite clear.

Looking at your attempted query I'm guessing that `Imported` and `Live` tables should be joined on both `key1` and `key2`. On top of that, if a pair `(key1, key2)` is not unique, the tables should be joined row-by-row in the order defined by `id` column.

Besides, both `key1` and `key2` can be `NULL`, so `NULL` values should be replaced with `0` and `"null"`.

**Query**

`rn_imported` and `rn_live` are sub-queries that have an extra column with row numbers generated by a `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Then these sub-queries are FULL joined together on `key1, key2, rn`.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/162aab/4/0).

```
SELECT
  imported_id
  ,live_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id AS imported_id
      ,COALESCE(key1, 0) AS key1
      ,COALESCE(key2, 'null') AS key2
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2 ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM imported
  ) AS rn_imported
  FULL JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      id AS live_id
      ,COALESCE(key1, 0) AS key1
      ,COALESCE(key2, 'null') AS key2
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2 ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM live
  ) AS rn_live
  ON rn_imported.key1 = rn_live.key1
  AND rn_imported.key2 = rn_live.key2
  AND rn_imported.rn = rn_live.rn
ORDER BY imported_id ASC NULLS LAST, live_id ASC NULLS LAST
```

**Result**

```
| imported_id | live_id |
|-------------|---------|
|           1 |      15 |
|           2 |      16 |
|           3 |      17 |
|           5 |  (null) |
|      (null) |      18 |
|      (null) |      19 |
```

---

To make this approach as efficient as possible, you should make your `key1` and `key2` columns `NOT NULL` to avoid calling the `COALESCE` function. The function itself is fast, but such use of the function usually makes it impossible to use an index. After the need for the function call is removed you should add an index on `(key1, key2, id)` in both tables. One index on three columns in this order. It won't hurt to make it unique index. It may give some extra hint to the optimiser. With this index `ROW_NUMBER` should be able to generate required numbers without extra sort. Having two sorted sets of data should also help the join.

I'd like to repeat. Adding just an index without making columns `NOT NULL` most likely would be useless.

Comment: Sorry if you don't understand everything, i try put at maximum details what i want. But when i look to your query it looks good and probably what i want. I will test it and if it will work bounty is yours ;)

Comment: @Perlos testing a query usually means trying it on some sample data that covers as many various interesting cases as possible. At first you manually determine what the correct result should look like for such sample data, then run a query and check if result is as expected. For this to work it is important to have a good set of sample data. If you can think of some more interesting cases that should be included in your sample data, edit your question and add more rows to the sample and to expected result. Thus I can fix the query if it is wrong in some cases, or others can write better answer.

Comment: Yes i want to rewrite to more simple question, so others can use it too.

Comment: I give you that bounty, because i haven't time change original query, bud test work :)